# Sessions in PHP5 - built-in sessions or not?

Tags: php, session

*The background:*
I am in the starting grounds of a new project built on PHP5.3. I've just started to look into ways of handling sessions in a way that initially lets me save the sessions to the database. I will separate all session management into a separate library to make it easy to transparentely migrate to *memcached*, *separate session database server*, or whatever that's the best solution by then.

I am kind of confused about what would be a good approach though - there's a lot of different ideas online on how to handle sessions varying dependent on the PHP version and the more I read, the more confused I get.

*The question:*
**Here's the options that I believe are the most appropriate. Which one should I use and why? Are there other alternatives that should be considered?**

**Option 1:**
Using `session_set_save_handler` and create custom functions for each session event to utilize the native (built-in) session handling of PHP to the fullest, but still save the sessions to database. Session would be written like `$_SESSION['identifier'] = 'value';`.

**Option 2:**
Building a complete session class which would have nothing to do with PHP's sessions and just act as any database model talking to the `sessions` table in my database. Session would be written like `$this->sessions->write('identifier', 'value');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you take the latter route, but with a cool twist.

Create a `Session` class, then use the adaptor pattern to extend it with `DatabaseSession` and `CookieSession` concrete classes.

Overriding the `session_save_handler` just seems to be too much of a hack in my honest opinion.

Routing all session-related interaction through your wrapper class gives you a lot more flexibility as the project gets increasingly larger.

Something like this:

```
interface SessionAdaptor {
   function write($key, $data, $timeout);
   function read($key);
   function key_exists($key);
}

class Session {
  private $adaptor;

  function __construct(SessionAdaptor $adaptor) {
     $this->adaptor = $adaptor;
  }

  //here we go:

  function write($key, $data, $timeout) {
     return $this->adaptor->write($key, $data, $timeout);
  }

  function read($key) {
     return $this->adaptor->read($key);
  }

  function key_exists($key) {
     return $this->adaptor->key_exists($key);
  }
}

class DatabaseSession implements SessionAdaptor {
   //...
}

class CookieSession implements SessionAdaptor {
   //...
}
```

Usage:

```
$database_session = new Session(new DatabaseSession());
```

Comment: Would the "head" `Session` class store to PHP sessions in your opinion when called separately?

Comment: @Industrial Nope, it'd just be an abstract superclass.

Comment: re `session_save_handler`: I wouldn't call that a hack - isn't that exactly what it's supposed to be for? http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: Hi again Jacob. Woudln't this affect the "transparency" I wanted earlier as I would need to call the `DatabaseSession` classes in my code, making a eventual future change to another way of storing sessions non-transparent?

Answer (score 8):

The `$_SESSION` superglobal is actually a pretty good feature in PHP.

Depending on what your software solution is going to end up to be, third-party users would be more accustomed to writing to and reading from this superglobal with your custom session handlers doing the magic in the background.

There's also good security enhancements available through [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/index.html) which you need not "worry about" when developing a session storage for yourself.